# str.find member function error

Tags: c++, function, find, member

I'm having trouble understanding why my code isn't changing the results of the output file. I tried using the "find" member function to check for the incorrect operators, but it doesn't seem change the results. How would I check to see if a string contains the string I'm looking for, then replace it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void input(ifstream& inputfile, ofstream& outputfile, string& cpp);

void edit(ifstream& inputfile, ofstream& outputfile, string& line);

int main()
{
    ifstream inputfile;
    ofstream outputfile;
    string line, cpp;

    input(inputfile,outputfile,cpp);

    edit(inputfile, outputfile, line);
}

void input(ifstream& inputfile, ofstream& outputfile, string& cpp)
{
    cout << "Enter a cpp file to modify" << endl;
    cin >> cpp;
    cout << endl;

    inputfile.open(cpp.c_str());
    if (inputfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "File opening failed,did you enter your file name correctly?" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    outputfile.open("cpp.txt");

}

void edit(ifstream& inputfile, ofstream& outputfile, string& line)
{
    string a = "cin <<";
    string b = "cout >>";

    getline(inputfile,line);

    while (! inputfile.eof())
    {
        line.find(a);
        if (line == a)
        {
            outputfile << "cin >>";
        }
        line.find(b);
        if (line == b)
        {
            outputfile << "cout >>";
        }
        else
            outputfile << line << endl;

        getline(inputfile,line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`find()` searches the string for the specified substring and then returns its position if found, it does not modify the string being searched.  You are ignoring the return value of `find()`.  Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void input(ifstream& inputfile, ofstream& outputfile, string& cpp);

void edit(ifstream& inputfile, ofstream& outputfile, string& line);

int main()
{
    ifstream inputfile;
    ofstream outputfile;
    string line, cpp;

    input(inputfile,outputfile,cpp);

    edit(inputfile, outputfile, line);
}

void input(ifstream& inputfile, ofstream& outputfile, string& cpp)
{
    cout << "Enter a cpp file to modify" << endl;
    cin >> cpp;
    cout << endl;

    inputfile.open(cpp.c_str());
    if (!inputfile)
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed, did you enter your file name correctly?" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    outputfile.open("cpp.txt");
    if (!outputfile)
    {
        cout << "Output file opening failed" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

void edit(ifstream& inputfile, ofstream& outputfile, string& line)
{
    string a = "cin <<";
    string b = "cout >>";

    while (getline(inputfile,line))
    {
        if (line.find(a) != std::string::npos)
        {
            outputfile << "cin >>";
        }
        else if (line.find(b) != std::string::npos)
        {
            outputfile << "cout >>";
        }
        else
            outputfile << line << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are intention is:

```
    if (line.find(a) != string::npos)
    {
        outputfile << "cin >>";
    }

    if (line.find(b) != string::npos)
    {
        outputfile << "cout >>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::string::find()`  doesn't change the string is called with. It tries to find the string or character posted as an argument and returns the position of the character found. All you have to do is check if the return value it doesn't equal `std::string::npos`, which is a value which means the substring wasn't found:

```
if (line.find(a) != std::string::npos) {
    ...
}

else if (line.find(b) != std::string::npos) {
    ...
}
```

Also, `while (!eof())` is generally seen as a bad programming practice. Perform the input within the loop parameters instead:

```
while (std::getline(inputfile, line)) {
    if (line.find(a) != std::string::npos) {
        outputfile << "cin >>";
    }

    else if (line.find(b) != std::string::npos) {
        outputfile << "cout <<";
    }

    else
        outputfile << line << std::endl;
}
```